# Merge two lists c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to merge two lists such that only one entry of common element is present in the merged queue.

```
std::list<int> list1 = { 5,9,0,1,3,4 };
std::list<int> list2 = { 8,7,2,6,4 }; 
list1.sort();
list2.sort();
std::cout << "list1:  " << list1 << "\n";
std::cout << "list2:  " << list2 << "\n";
list1.merge(list2);
std::cout << "merged: " << list1 << "\n";
```

The output looks like:

```
list1:   0 1 3 4 5 9
list2:   2 4 6 7 8
merged:  0 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I want the output to look like:

```
list1:   0 1 3 4 5 9
list2:   2 4 6 7 8
merged:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Use [std::unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list1.sort();
list1.unique();
```

since your list is sorted just call `unique`

```
list1.unique();
```

your full code:

```
std::list<int> list1 = { 5,9,0,1,3,4 };
std::list<int> list2 = { 8,7,2,6,4 }; 
list1.sort();
list2.sort();
std::cout << "list1:  " << list1 << "\n";
std::cout << "list2:  " << list2 << "\n";
list1.merge(list2);
list1.unique();
std::cout << "merged: " << list1 << "\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of big codes:

```
std::list<int> list1 = { 5,9,0,1,3,4 };
std::list<int> list2 = { 8,7,2,6,4 }; 

list1.splice(list1.end(), list2);
list1.sort();
list1.unique();
```

`list1` now contains one copy of each element from the original `list1` and `list2`. The first step transfers the content of `list2` into into `list1`. The second step sorts the elements. The last step throws out duplicates. There is little benefit in sorting the lists separately and later merging.

Answer (score 1):

Else, you can use `std::set` to maintain a collection of the unique data. Here's how i modded your code:

```
  std::list<int> list1 = { 5,9,0,1,3,4 };
  std::list<int> list2 = { 8,7,2,6,4 }; 

  std::set<int> unq(list1.begin(),list1.end()); //initialize with list 1 
  unq.insert(list2.begin(),list2.end()); //now insert list 2 completely 

  //Print new data

  for(std::set<int>::iterator it=unq.begin();it!=unq.end();it++)
     cout<<*it<<" ";
```

Comment: If at all you want to use `std::set`, then you can other overload of constructor and `insert` to **avoid the manual loops**: `std::set<int> unq(list1.begin(), list1.end());` and then add the second list as:   `unq.insert(list2.begin(), list2.end());` . Just two lines is enough.

Comment: Thanks. I have made the changes